# Need help deciphering a code of javascript confetti

Tags: javascript

The code of javascript confetti is [here](https://codepen.io/Pillowfication/pen/PNEJbY?editors=0010).

I'm trying to define the colors of confetti rather than letting them be random (the default setting).

I had found that the variable for deciding colors is an array called `colorThemes`, which contains several colors:

```
var colorThemes = [
  function() {
    return color(200 * random()|0, 200 * random()|0, 200 * random()|0);
  }, function() {
    ......
  }, function() {
    ......
  },
```

But after I change the first array item to the following format, all confetti become the same color (white in this case):

```
var colorThemes = [
  function() {
    return 'rgb(255, 255, 255)';
  },
```

And line 191 seems to control if the colors are randomly selected or is the first one:

```
var theme = colorThemes[onlyOnKonami ? colorThemes.length * random()|0 : 0]
```

I had tried changing it to try to force selecting random color, but still had no luck:

```
var theme = colorThemes[colorThemes.length * random()|0]
```

Comment: Well, if you just return a single string representing white then you'll only get white. You'd need to define an array of colors and pick colors from that array at random.

Comment: What is the question? Being the same color is the expected result if you change it to the white color code rather than generating random ones.

Comment: The function returns a random color, so changign it to white will obv turn everything that uses the function into white. And the part that controls the other settings, is not included in this code.

Comment: `colorThemes` is an array of colors. I only changed one of the colors to white. That isn't suppose to make all confetti white.

Comment: @IanY. — You need to provide a [mcve] in the question itself.

Comment: @Quentin I would have done that if I'm able to. I don't know if you have checked the codepen entry or not, but all the effects are controlled by JS and it cannot be reduced.

Comment: @IanY. — That's why you need to do your own debugging and break the problem down into something that can demonstrate it here.

Comment: Take a look at line 191

Comment: @Quentin The code itself is like a jQuery plugin. If you are able to break it down into a "minimal" version, I'd be interested to see that.

Comment: @Trey Thank you. I forgot to mention that I had tried changing line 191 to `var theme = colorThemes[colorThemes.length * random()|0]` but still had no luck.

Comment: @IanY. — The goal is to break it down into some minimal code which demonstrates the problem, not which reproduces the entire end result. You don't need to display the graphics, just look at the function which repeatedly gets the white colour instead of the colour you expect and then output the colour with console.log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So when the color gets set on line 191, it gets set before the "addConfetto" function is called, that function called recursively based on the spread setting to create the new particles. Since the theme function has already been determined, every particle uses the same one. There are 2 options, you could create a function that returns a random color out of an array of predefined colors, and use that rather than the randomly chosen function, something like this:

```
colorTheme(){
    var colors = [
        "rgb(255, 255, 255)",
        "rgb(0, 255, 255)",
        "rgb(255, 255, 0)"
    ];
    return colors.length * random|0;

}
```

and change 191 to:

```
var theme = colorTheme;
```

Or dig a little deeper into the Confetti class and alter where the theme function gets called on line 137:

```
innerStyle.backgroundColor = colorThemes[Math.floor(colorThemes.length * random())]();
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Since my goal is to manually define colors as `var colorThemes = [function() { return 'rgb(...)' }, function() { return 'rgb(...)' }, ...]`, I will make it go with the second option then.